# Getting combinations of elements from from different pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that I have a dataframe like this:

```
Date Artist           percent_gray percent_blue percent_black percent_red 
33   Leonardo             22           33            36          46
45   Leonardo             23           47            23          14
46   Leonardo             13           34            33          12
23   Michelangelo         28           19            38          25
25   Michelangelo         24           56            55          13
26   Michelangelo         21           22            45          13
13   Titian               24           17            23          22
16   Titian               45           43            44          13 
19   Titian               17           45            56          13
24   Raphael              34           34            34          45
27   Raphael              31           22            25          67
```

I want to get maximum color differences of different pictures for the same artist. I can also compare `percent_gray` with `percent_blue` e.g. for Lenoardo the biggest difference is `percent_red` `(date:46)` - `percent_blue(date:45) =`12 - 47 = -35. I wanna see how it evolves over time, so I just wanna compare new pictures of the same artist with the old ones(in this case I can compare third picture with first and second ones, and second picture only with first one) and get the maximum differences. So dataframe should look like

```
Date Artist          max_d 
33   Leonardo         NaN   
45   Leonardo         -32   
46   Leonardo         -35    
23   Michelangelo     NaN   
25   Michelangelo      37 
26   Michelangelo     -43   
13   Titian           NaN 
16   Titian            28   
19   Titian            43
24   Raphael          NaN   
27   Raphael           33
```

I think I have to use groupby but couldn't manage to get the output I want.

Comment: Can you explain more? Why for Titian is not difference `-43` between max `56` and min `13`? Why first value is `NaN`? How do you get `33`? Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry for titian it is -43, I just did it manually. first values are NaN because they are the first pictures that they draw, I wanna compare only new ones with older ones

Comment: Ok, how do you get `-34, 37, 27, 33`?

Comment: I should change them. damn, just a sec

Comment: should be alright

Comment: Thank you, I get `-32, -35`. But instead `37` I get `-25`. What is formula for `37`?

Comment: differences of precent_blues: 56-19

Comment: it can be blue blue also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141964/discussion-between-jezrael-and-cenk-mitir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#first sort in real data
df = df.sort_values(['Artist', 'Date'])
mi = df.iloc[:,2:].min(axis=1)
ma = df.iloc[:,2:].max(axis=1)
ma1 = ma.groupby(df['Artist']).shift()
mi1 = mi.groupby(df['Artist']).shift()
mad1 = mi - ma1
mad2 = ma - mi1
df['max_d'] = np.where(mad1.abs() > mad2.abs(), mad1, mad2)
print (df)
    Date        Artist  percent_gray  percent_blue  percent_black  \
0     33      Leonardo            22            33             36   
1     45      Leonardo            23            47             23   
2     46      Leonardo            13            34             33   
3     23  Michelangelo            28            19             38   
4     25  Michelangelo            24            56             55   
5     26  Michelangelo            21            22             45   
6     13        Titian            24            17             23   
7     16        Titian            45            43             44   
8     19        Titian            17            45             56   
9     24       Raphael            34            34             34   
10    27       Raphael            31            22             25   

    percent_red  max_d  
0            46    NaN  
1            14  -32.0  
2            12  -35.0  
3            25    NaN  
4            13   37.0  
5            13  -43.0  
6            22    NaN  
7            13   28.0  
8            13   43.0  
9            45    NaN  
10           67   33.0
```

Explanation (with new columns):

```
#get min and max per rows
df['min'] = df.iloc[:,2:].min(axis=1)
df['max'] = df.iloc[:,2:].max(axis=1)
#get shifted min and max by Artist
df['max1'] = df.groupby('Artist')['max'].shift()
df['min1'] = df.groupby('Artist')['min'].shift()
#get differences
df['max_d1'] = df['min'] - df['max1']
df['max_d2'] = df['max'] - df['min1']
#if else of absolute values
df['max_d'] = np.where(df['max_d1'].abs() > df['max_d2'].abs(), df['max_d1'], df['max_d2'])
print (df)
    percent_red  min  max  max1  min1  max_d1  max_d2  max_d  
0            46   22   46   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  
1            14   14   47  46.0  22.0   -32.0    25.0  -32.0  
2            12   12   34  47.0  14.0   -35.0    20.0  -35.0  
3            25   19   38   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  
4            13   13   56  38.0  19.0   -25.0    37.0   37.0  
5            13   13   45  56.0  13.0   -43.0    32.0  -43.0  
6            22   17   24   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  
7            13   13   45  24.0  17.0   -11.0    28.0   28.0  
8            13   13   56  45.0  13.0   -32.0    43.0   43.0  
9            45   34   45   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  
10           67   22   67  45.0  34.0   -23.0    33.0   33.0
```

And if use second explanation solution, remove columns:

```
df = df.drop(['min','max','max1','min1','max_d1', 'max_d2'], axis=1)
print (df)
    Date        Artist  percent_gray  percent_blue  percent_black  \
0     33      Leonardo            22            33             36   
1     45      Leonardo            23            47             23   
2     46      Leonardo            13            34             33   
3     23  Michelangelo            28            19             38   
4     25  Michelangelo            24            56             55   
5     26  Michelangelo            21            22             45   
6     13        Titian            24            17             23   
7     16        Titian            45            43             44   
8     19        Titian            17            45             56   
9     24       Raphael            34            34             34   
10    27       Raphael            31            22             25   

    percent_red  max_d  
0            46    NaN  
1            14  -32.0  
2            12  -35.0  
3            25    NaN  
4            13   37.0  
5            13  -43.0  
6            22    NaN  
7            13   28.0  
8            13   43.0  
9            45    NaN  
10           67   33.0
```

Comment: If I say sort by artist and date it will automatically produce the result right? I will run the code but it will take so long as dataset is large

Comment: Yes, sorting is necessery first.

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom apply function. Does this work?

```
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas
import itertools

p = pandas.read_csv('Artits.tsv', sep='\s+')

def diff(x):
    return x

def max_any_color(cols):
    grey = []
    blue = []
    black = []
    red = []
    for row in cols.iterrows():
        date = row[1]['Date']
        grey.append(row[1]['percent_gray'])
        blue.append(row[1]['percent_blue'])
        black.append(row[1]['percent_black'])
        red.append(row[1]['percent_red'])


    gb = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(grey,blue)])
    gblack = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(grey,black)])
    gr = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(grey,red)])
    bb = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(blue,black)])
    br = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(blue,red)])
    blackr = max([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in itertools.product(black,red)])

    l = [gb,gblack,gr,bb,br,blackr]
    c = ['grey/blue','grey/black','grey/red','blue/black','blue/red','black/red']
    max_ = max(l)
    between_colors_index = l.index(max_)
    return c[between_colors_index], max_ 

p.groupby('Artist').apply(lambda x: max_any_color(x))
```

Output:

```
Leonardo         (blue/red, 35)
Michelangelo     (blue/red, 43)
Raphael          (blue/red, 45)
Titian          (black/red, 43)
```

Comment: Well actually, in my real data set they are not really numbers, I just wrote numbers for simplicity, so you will not know the biggest difference until you get the differences

Comment: the function finds the max no matter what it is